# how to detect Compatible CLDC version of Phones?

Tags: xhtml, cldc

i am currently working on mobile base xhtml site.
in this site i have to do download page.
for this i need to detect Compatible  CLDC version of  Phone.
please help me.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side, you read the HTTP "User-Agent" header that should be attached to any HTTP request.

Match it against [WFURL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) to figure out what you need to do to support the device (i.e. adapt your generated CSS code to the handset screen size...).